# i18n Pluralization of a sentence with multiple counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

Looks like I got to a real challenge...

I want to translate the following sentence:

> You got XX new messages in YY forums

I already used translation pluralization, but this one is different since instead of array of pluralization I need a n-dimensions matrix when n is number of elements which need to be pluralized, in this case 2.

Any idea??

Comment: Can you explain some more, with a concrete example instead of using X & Y, of what text you would want to display, and what the conditions are?

Comment: XX and YY stand for the counters, I thought it was obvious. For example: __You got 26 new messages in 3 forums__

Comment: Why would it be obvious when you didn't mention anything about messages and forums in your question?  I still don't know how "the n-dimensions matrix" comes into it either, i may just be being thick though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pluralize sentence with more than 1 `:count`. The simplest way to deal with it is to split your sentence into 2 parts: `You got XX new messages`, `in YY forums` and pluralize them separately.

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the answer. The problem is that might be languages this simple split won't work. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Doing pluralisation twice inside an I18n'ised string is always going to be complicated as you say.  You could make a helper for it: you can then build more complicated logic into the helper.